# Angular5 Remove Default Padding

Tags: containers, angular5, padding, default, margins

I have started a default Angular 5 CLI app...

```
ng new testApp
```

I then changed the background app.component.html to gray so you can see my issue...

```
<div style="text-align:center; background:gray">
```

The default app always has these unnecessary gaps (margins? padding?) between the browser's edge and the first level of content (container?). What is the easiest, most direct way to remove these gaps completely? There should be a single value I can change somewhere to fix this, right?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is the margin of the body and the margin of

```
<h1> Welcome to app! </h1>
```

Comment: I added "_ngcontent-c0" to both the h1 tag and the higher-up <div> and it didn't make a difference. however, I don't think it's the h1. I can completely remove that tag and section and the gray background still shows the gap.

Comment: No!, you don't need to add `_ngcontent-c0 ` you need in `style.css ` write `body{margin:0}` and remove the element `h1` from `app.component.html`

Comment: The correct short answer is:  write body{margin:0} in style.css. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers have `body` `margin`s. Set those to 0.

Comment: I have attempted setting body, main, container {margin: 0; padding: 0} for several objects and tags  by way of .css and directly in html, and still haven't been successful. My point is that instead of blasting .css updates all over the place to remove this issue, it seems like there would be a single place, a single file where you can remove this default gap for the main container. By the way, it's present in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge... that's more than just some browsers - I believe it's likely true for most if not all.

Comment: consider using your dev tools to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Use in  app.component.scss

```css
::ng-deep * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```